# overflow:hidden does not work

Tags: css, html, overflow

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/ybCN5/

I do not know why it does not work.
 I've tried different ways and still cannot find a solution. I'm going to use this box for jquery sliding.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please put the important parts of the code here and give us some explanation on what we are looking at. Sorry most of us aren't mind readers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `position:absolute;` is causing the element(.sldtitulo) to escape its parent. You need to give the parent that you want it to not overflow a `position` with a value that is not `static`.

Comment: Added `position:relative;` in .sldcontent and `postion:absolute;` in .sldtitulo and works, code:http://jsfiddle.net/ybCN5/4/                   thanks for your answer was helpful.

Comment: So, does that answer your question?